# Invalid variance in complex generics

Tags: c#, generics, compiler-errors, covariance, contravariance

I catched this typical compilation error:

> Invalid variance: The type parameter 'K' must be covariantly valid on
>   'ConsoleApplication3.IQuery'. 'K' is contravariant.

I am familiar with the basics of [Covariance and Contravariance in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx), but I still can't get why it is wrong:

```
interface IQuery<in D>
{
}

interface IDct<in K>
{
}
         // error here ↓
interface IDctQuery<in K> : IQuery<IDct<K>>
{
}
```

Please, explain me

**UPD**

It is interesting that this code is completely valid:

```
interface IQuery<out D>
{
}

interface IDct<out K>
{
}

interface IDctQuery<out K> : IQuery<IDct<K>>
{
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is happening is that by using a contravariant type as a type parameter of another contravariat type, that reverses the direction of the type parameter K. Sounds confusing, but this works fine:

```
interface IDctQuery<in K> : IQuery<K>
{
}
```

because K is contravariant in `IDctQuery` and `IQuery`. But once you add `IDct` as a type parameter, the requirement on K is now to be covariant. So you need to change to

```
interface IDctQuery<out K> : IQuery<IDct<K>>
{
}
```

Lets say you have two classes, `Dog` and `Animal`. A `Dog` is an `Animal` and a covariant interface preserves this relationship. So `IEnumerable<Dog>` can be assigned to an `IEnumerable<Animal>`.

A contravariant interface reverses this relationship. So an `IQuery<Animal>` can be assigned to an `IQuery<Dog>` and an **`IDct<Animal>` can be assigned to an `IDct<Dog>`**.

Your interface declaration:

```
interface IDctQuery<in K> : IQuery<IDct<K>>
{
}
```

says that an `IDctQuery<Animal>` can be assigned to an `IDctQuery<Dog>` from that it follows that `IQuery<IDct<Animal>>` can be assigned to `IQuery<IDct<Dog>>` and because `IQuery` is contravariant it means that **`IDct<Dog>` can be assigned to `IDct<Animal>`** which is not true because `IDict` is contravariant and `IDct<Animal>` can be assigned to an `IDct<Dog>` but not the other way around.

Comment: Sorry for my blindness, but... why? Also, look at the update please

Comment: @astef - Covariance maintains the direction of type relationships, so nested covariant parameters should work. The confusion is that when you have nested contravariant parameters, you are reversing the direction twice, so you end up with a covariant relationship.

Comment: @Lee And further "contavariant nesting" will reverse it at each level of nesting, right?